# ASP.NET Web Application Error

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, web-config

I have an application with the main and 2 sub pages. The main page works  and one of the sub pages work fine. But the other sub page gives me an error:

> Runtime Error 
>   Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 
>   Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

When trying to run on my local, i get

> An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. The server may not be configured for access to the requested URL.

These were working fine a week ago and this problem is sudden. help please.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this issue because the SubPage you are getting error on accessing might be under some security. The error you have described comes on a page which is not accessible to the anonymous user.

You must check the Web.config firstly to see if there is some Location Access permissions defined for that Webpage and ensure that they are correctly defined.

You may read about more to this problem by a previous Answer.

[web site configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033878/web-site-configuration)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My issue is that this was previously working properly and crash is sudden. Also, my web.config has no Location access permission. And as I said, one of the sub pages work fine and the other does not....